# Как применить один цвет на две дивы через css?

Tags: css

Как применить один цвет на две дивы через css? Можно сделать так?
Например

```
color: #000;

div1 {
    color: color;
}
div2 {
    background: color;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непосредственно через CSS не получится. Только через препроцессоры вроде [less](http://lesscss.org/), [sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [stylus](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/)

На этот счет есть неплохая [статья](http://frontender.info/starting-css/)

Comment: Ммм а есть другой вариант, если знаете пожалуйста скажите. А как можно сделать через less, sass, stylus или можно через javascript? Как можно гуглить?

Comment: У всех перечисленных есть возможность собирать стили прямо в браузере. Другое дело, что это не всегда необходимо. Мне кажется, что стили стОит собирать на стороне сервера, минимизировать, упаковывать и кешировать, потом отдавать клиенту готовый .css файл

Comment: Ну вы прав я просто хотел сделать такой [сайт](http://7themes.su/) и изменить цвет через css

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент поддержка переменных в CSS есть только в FireFox http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Пример

```
:root {
    --color-alert: #ff0000;
}
.div1 {
      color: var(--color-alert);
}
.div2 {
      background-color: var(--color-alert);
}
```

Тест http://jsfiddle.net/fv3ca2m7/

Comment: Спасибо но это по-моему не удобно

Comment: Не знал. Плюсую. Осталось дождаться когда это станет более распространенной практикой.